# MultipartFile is null

Tags: spring-boot, postman, multipartfile

I'm trying to post multipartfile with postman, but comes null

I have the following method in my controller. Controller accepts null instead of multipartfile

```
@PostMapping("/upload_bpmn_with_body")
    fun uploadBPMN(@RequestBody fileBPMN: MultipartFile): CProcess {
        return serviceProcesses.save(serviceBPMN.parseBPMN(fileBPMN))
    }
```

I also added the following lines for multipartfile to the application.yml file, but this did not solve the problem

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost/workflow
    username: workflow
    password: workflow
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true

  servlet:
    multipart:
      enabled: true
```

Comment: There are some articles and answers here on SO regarding this. Please try to replace `@RequestBody` with `@RequestParam`. It should look something like this:  `fun uploadBPMN(@RequestParam("file") fileBPMN: MultipartFile`)

Comment: Tried that too, but it didn't work. Now I also changed the sending settings in postman and everything worked, thanks